# Error for if statement in Python

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to write a function which takes a giving 2x2 matrix and checks if one of its elements is large than a certain value. If this is the case, it returns 1, otherwise it should return 0. Up to now I have:
(EDIT: correct code below)

```
def Is_it_too_large(W_n, max_value):
   value_1 = abs( W_n[0,0] )
   value_2 = abs( W_n[0,1] )
   value_3 = abs( W_n[1,0] )
   value_4 = abs( W_n[1,1] )
   if value_1 < max_value and value_2 < max_value and value_3 < max_value and value_4 < max_value:
       return False
   else:
       return True
```

However, if I test the function with, for example,

```
A = np.matrix([[1,3,7],[2,8,3],[7,8,1]])
print Is_it_too_large(A,10)
```

I get the error "invalid syntax". Any ideas what is wrong here?

Comment: FIrst of all it is a `2x2` matrix **not** a `4x4` matrix

Comment: "However, this does not seem to work." is not a precise problem description.

Comment: @anmol_uppal you are right, typo!

Comment: @Nsh I have added a "precise" problem description.

Comment: Also instead of letting `0` and `1` implicitly be converted to `True` and `False`, why not just use those literals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want `and` instead of `&&`.

Answer (score 1):

Python does not support the '&&' operator you have to use 'and' instead of '&&'